# How do I test Moose subtype error messages?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, moose, subtype, test-more

I use Moose subtypes for attributes and want to test (Test::More) their correct handling of constraint-violating input.  Currently Mooses's internal error handling makes my testfile stop completely when it sees the invalid data.

Module source (minimized for stackoverflow.com):

```
package Doctor;
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
subtype 'Phone_nr_t'
   => as 'Str'
   => where { $_ =~ /^\+?[0-9 ]+$/ }
   => message { 'A Phone_nr must be blabla' };
has 'fax' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Phone_nr_t');
```

Test source:

```
use Test::More tests=>1;
use Doctor;

my $testdoc=Doctor->new(fax=>'0341 2345678');
throws_ok { $testdoc->fax('123,456') }
    qr('A Phone_nr must be blabla'),
    'fax shall reject bad numbers';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and to the Perl tag. This is a very good first question! I'm looking forward to more. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please `use strict` before you post on StackOverflow. You have not included `use Test::Exception;` so you don't have `throws_ok`. If you include that your code almost works.

This works:

```
throws_ok { $testdoc->fax('123,456') }
    Moose::Exception::ValidationFailedForInlineTypeConstraint,
    'fax shall reject bad numbers';
```

Also your definition of the regular expression pattern is wrong. It tries to match quotes which don't exist.

```
throws_ok { $testdoc->fax('123,456') }
    qr(A Phone_nr must be blabla),
    'fax shall reject bad numbers';
```

Comment: Actually the `{}` part of the `qr` is not the problem. The single quotes inside of the expression are. `qr(foo)` or `qr'foo'` both would be perfectly fine, as would `qr/foo/`.

Comment: I had `use strict` on my PC (I always use a template with that and more), just minimized it away here (and then the `Moose::Exception::vali...` thing requires quotes too).  Test::Exception was missing because I had compiled a more recent perl to use Marpa.  Now all is fine, both answers work.